# Show Spreadsheet component in Vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin, spreadsheet, vaadin10

I'm using Vaadin 10 and I want to show a spreadsheet to the user. However, the method below is giving me an error:

```
public class SomeUI extends VerticalLayout{

   private SomeUI(){

       // ... some add(Components)
       String path = "C:\\Users\\MY_USERNAME\\Desktop";
       Spreadsheet sp = ExcelOpener.openFile(path);

       // this line does not work
       // add(sp);
   }
}
```

Below is the ExcelOpener helper class:

```
public class ExcelOpener {

    public static Spreadsheet openFile(String path){
        // I will use the path to open given excel later.
        // Right now I want to open an empty spreadsheet and show it to the user
        Spreadsheet spreadsheet = null;
        spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();

        return spreadsheet;
    }
}
```

My questions are:

- How can I solve add(sp) method's error:

> Cannot resolve method 'add(com.vaadin.addon.spreadsheet.Spreadsheet)'

- How can I open an excel with the given path? Is the path I have written is correct? Or should it be `"C:/Users/MY_USERNAME/Desktop"`

Comment: What version of the SpreadSheet are you using?  Could be the one for v8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Spreadsheet component is not compatible with Vaadin 10+ (only Vaadin7/8).

As you can see in the comments here https://vaadin.com/blog/vaadin-s-frontend-direction it is said:

> Last part is Spreadsheet, and that one is a bit tricky. It is built on
>   top of POI directly, and most of the logic happens on the server side,
>   so it can't really work as a stand-alone client-side web component
>   without a major shift in architecture. We don't have plans today to
>   make it into a web component, but we have a couple promising avenues
>   that we are looking into which could bring it to Flow. First one is
>   that we are looking into a migration tool, or wrapper, from 8 to 10.
>   It basically embeds a Vaadin 8 app within a Vaadin 10 app. We have a
>   proof of concept with Spreadsheet for FW8 wrapped alone and embedded
>   within a full Vaadin 10 app. The other option is a proof of concept of
>   taking a compiled Vaadin 8 GWT widget and building a web component
>   around that, found here: https://github.com/Legioth/connector-element.
>   In it's essence, it replaces the server-side counterpart of Vaadin 8
>   and hooks itself up to the connector of the widget. This could enable
>   us to compile the Spreadsheet widget into an web component, migrate
>   the server side of Spreadsheet to Flow, and connect the server side
>   back to the web component. We do not, however, any concrete plans on
>   if we are going to do this.